# Register-SPWorkflowService : Failed to query the OAuth S2S metadata endpoint

Tags: workflow, powershell, administration, installation, workflow-manager

I have the following:-

1. windows server 2012 R2.
2. SharePoint server 2016
3. i install workflow manager 1.0 on the same sharepoint server.

now i want to register the workflow with the sharepoint server, so i did the following:-

1. I create a new site collection of type team site at `/sites/workflow` to be used as the workflow site collection.
2. I run the following command:-

   Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://server****/sites/workflow" -WorkflowHostUri "http://server****:12291"

but i got this exception:-

> Register-SPWorkflowService : Failed to query the OAuth S2S metadata
>   endpoint at URI
>   'http://server****/sites/workflow/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1'. Error
>   details: 'The metadata endpoint responded with an error. HTTP status
>   code: Forbidden.'. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   5d48cbb3-bbb6-4df0-9b9c-30fd797f3e12. NodeId: server****. Scope:
>   /SharePoint. Client ActivityId : 494ae29d-f307-20df-99b9-1bf9ffef837a.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://server****/sites/workflow"
>   -WorkflowH ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:    RegisterSPWorkflowService)
>   [Register-SPWorkflowService], InvalidRequestExc   eption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell
>   .RegisterSPWorkflowService

3. so i went to central administration >> managed services >> workflow service>>i add the farm account inside the administration group for the service.
4. then i try to re-run the command, but i got the same error.
5. now i try using `-AllowOAuthHttp` as follow, but i got the exact error:-

   Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://server****/sites/workflow" -WorkflowHostUri "http://server****:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp
6. also when i try to access the following url `sites/workflow/_layouts/15/metadata/json/1` i got 403 HTTP error...

so can anyone advice on this.. now all the articles i read about this error contain the above 2 solutions.

1. add the farm account inside the administration group for the managed service.
2. use -AllowOAuthHttp . but seems in my case they did not fix the problem..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this issue in past when configured the workflow manager. In my situation, I ends up doing the following.

1. I removed the workflow manager service application using this command...`Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy | Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy`
2. Now i I run the same register command with -force parameter like this.`Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://server****/sites/workflow" -WorkflowHostUri "http://server****:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force`

Comment: but why do this work? and how can i configure STS?